# Is the initial block in Verilog sythesizable?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, synthesis, vivado

I have come across a lot of posts which say that the `initial` block is not synthesizable in Verilog HDL. According to [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-81-322-2791-5%2F1.pdf) appendix on synthesizable and non-synthesizable Verilog constructs (from the book Digital Logic Design Using Verilog by Taraate), the `initial` block is not synthesizable.

I prefer using a reset to initialize any content in memory blocks.
But my friends are doing a gaming project where they set the initial positions (values) of blocks using an initial keyword (we're using a Nexys 4 DDR FPGA). It worked.

I really don't know what to say because I thought it was not possible. Can you please explain this to me? I'm using Xilinx Vivado.

Comment: My guess it works because you're using an FPGA. One generally just can preload the registers (and about everything) in those with the programming bitstreams. However, in 'real silicon', without a PoR circuit and reset magic, the registers may power up in just about any state they like. _I don't know, it's just a guess._ That said, I can't see why there couldn't be a silicon synthesizer that would do the PoR handling for you.

Comment: I believed the same about the signal initialization and was surprised... But it looks like the tool vendors are feeling too free adding non-standard features which are doing more mess than order, if you ask me...

Comment: Thanks @RichardtheSpacecat. But as Eugene Sh mentioned that vendors might have added these features and this varies with the tool we're using.

Comment: Don't use reset to initialize memory bocks, this will result in using a very large number of registers instead of distributed or block RAM.

Comment: @alex.forencich Is there any other way to initialize the content? Please let me know.

Comment: Not really.  If it's a ROM, then use an initial block.  If it's a RAM, then you have to use a state machine to load in the new values from somewhere.  If you use a reset signal, then the logic must be implemented as flip-flops as RAMs are not resettable.

Answer (score 4):

Xilinx Vivado can synthesize `initial` blocks in some cases. For example, [Vivado Synthesis Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) (page 145) shows how to initialize RAM contents.

```
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] ram [DEPTH-1:0];
integer i;
initial for (i=0; i<DEPTH; i=i+1) ram[i] = 0;
end
```

According to page 147, `$readmemb` can also be used to initialize a RAM.

```
reg [31:0] ram [0:63];

initial begin
    $readmemb(“rams_20c.data”, ram, 0, 63);
end
```

If we talk about ASIC, Design Compiler doesn't synthesize[<sup>*</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793397/3885596) these blocks.

Comment: Yes. But they also used system function $readmemb for reading the data file which is not synthesizable. (Can we consider the immediate above example that you've mentioned for synthesis?)

Comment: @SandeepI I've updated the answer regarding `$readmemb`.

Comment: Your answer is very misleading...`initial` blocks **in general** are not synthesizable. These code examples are not synthesized in the normal sense of the word. Clearly, the FPGA can not access a RAM data file directly. The desired RAM contents are embedded in the bit stream for programming the FPGA **before** the FPGA is actually configured.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson No, you are misinterpreting my answer. I do not claim that FPGA is reading a data file after configured. If content of the file is embedded in the bit stream, it means that it has been synthesized. When the FPGA is powered up, the RAM will have the data in it.

Comment: Your first sentence is that "Vivado can synthesize initial blocks". This is not true **in general** but only for specific cases. I wouldn't use the word "synthesis" to describe initializing a RAM...to me, "synthesis" is the process of converting HDL to a specific hardware implementation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I updated the sentence then. For "synthesis", I still disagree. In FPGAs, I don't see any difference between initializing a RAM or a LUT. If you say that we cannot use the word "synthesis" for RAM initialization, we should never use it for FPGAs at all.

Comment: As an additional comment, Intel PSG , former Altera, also supports initializing a memory using initial block. The reason, I think, is that both manufacturers wanted to provide tools to infer RAMs without having to resort to IP usage. And I think it is good, because inferred blocks are obviously more reusable than IP blocks.